# Whiteboard APIs which can be used in Web and Mobile applications

Tags: api, web-applications, mobile-application

Are there any Whiteboard APIs (commercial/open source) that can be used in web and mobile applications? 
Features required:

- Two-way interactivity
- Multiple boards
- Ability to save work as PDF/PNG
- Features like zoom